# property forEach does not exist on type NodeListOf

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 2.4.4, TypeScript 2.1.5, PhpStorm 2017.2.1
I write this code:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone');
list.forEach(() => {
```

But the second line is underlined with a red line and TsLint reports that "property forEach does not exist on type NodeListOf"
But when I ctrl+click the `forEach` it gets me to `lib.es6.d.ts` where `forEach` is declared for `interface NodeListOf<TNode extends Node>`

Why it won't let me use it? What is wrong?

Comment: What lib are you using? is it es6 or are you using an older version?

Comment: What is lib in this context? I am maintaining an old project by another team. Maybe something is misconfigured but don't know where to look.

Comment: in your tsconfig.json. What lib is your project using?

Comment: It's ['dom', 'es6']

Comment: Okay I thought you might have had a mismatch/ been using an older version but looks like no. Sorry.

Comment: Can you try adding this to the first line: `const list = document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone') as NodeList;`

Comment: no `forEach` in this type either. And no, it's not a typo in `forEach`. I can Ctrl+click it.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need to convert it to an array:

```
const frameZones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone'));
frameZones.forEach((...) => {});
```

Comment: Correct or not, at least in actually helps. I am not sure. The question in actuality remains open. Why does PhpStorm claim it has this method?

Comment: Actually, with ES6 you can approach this even more easily: `const frameZones = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone')];` Cheers!

Answer (score 39):

Just add `"dom.iterable"` to `tsconfig.json`, so that it looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable"
        ],
...
```

Comment: I'm ok with accepting this if it solves the original issue.

Comment: Alternatively, just do: `"compilerOptions": { "target": "es2015" }`

Comment: It's important to mention that If you target es2015, your bundle may not work properly  on older browsers. It may be a solution (I haven't tried) but it has consequences

Comment: This solved it for me! Previous solutions referencing `es2015` did not apply, my project is already `module: es2020` and `target: es2019`.

Answer (score 14):

You can cast it to let compiler know it can be iterated:

```
(document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone') as any as Array<HTMLElement>).forEach();
```

Comment: if you are not using trailing `;` on lines, you will need to start with one `;(document`...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to cast your `document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone');` with `NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34495797)

Comment: a querySelectorAll<element> returns a NodeListOf<Element>. So my answer is totally correct. I have put a question mark to not sound to assertive.

Answer (score -3):

try to cast it:

```
const list = (NodeListOf) document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone');
```

ah typescript maybe like this:

```
const list = <NodeListOf> document.querySelectorAll('path.frame-zone');
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't help. Lint already knows what type it is.

Comment: type its NodeListOf or NodeList !?

Comment: It's NodeListOf

Comment: It's NodeListOf<Element>. I can cast it to NodeListOf<Node> but with no change.

Comment: check interface its like this ? : interface NodeListOf<TNode extends Node> extends Array<TNode> {}

Comment: extends Array<TNode> ?

Comment: Ctrl+Click on querySelectorAll gives this:
`querySelectorAll(selectors: string): NodeListOf<Element>;`
Ctrl+click on NodeListOf gives this:
`interface NodeListOf<TNode extends Node> {`

Comment: The original question shows that casting to NodeListOf is not the problem. The issue is that the TypeScript does not think that NodeListOf has any Array like methods - so it's a typing issue